# Is it possible to interact with a Resharper API from the c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, resharper

Think about the .NET Framework instructions `Debugger.IsAttached()` or `Debugger.Break()`, they make easy to interact with an external exe (the debugger) from inside the source code.

Is it possible to do something similar with Resharper? For example to do a full text search on the current solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a ReSharper plugin using [ReSharper SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=resharper-sdk).